# Using delimiter to take sum of numbers from input

Tags: java, delimiter

I am trying to write a code that takes input from this form "Piet van Gogh_5 6 7 4 5 6", and gives me the sum of the integers from this input. I seem to have a problem with using the delimiter, as the first integer comes after a _ and the following integers all come after a white space.

Here is the code that I have written so far:

```
void firstline() {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    out.printf("");
    String Line = in.nextLine();
    Scanner line = new Scanner(Line);

    int somcijfers = 0;
    while(line.hasNext()) {
        somcijfers += line.nextInt();
    }

    out.printf("%d", somcijfers);       
}

void start() {
    firstline();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Scanner::useDelimiter()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter-java.lang.String-) may help.

Comment: You could read the line, String.split by _ then split index 1 of that result by space. Use Integer.parseInt to convert the strings to integers.

Comment: You should • format your code properly • follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names always start with lowercase • avoid mixing up Dutch and English variable names: you'd better use either language.

Answer (score 3):

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
    String line = br.readLine();
    String[] splitLine = line.split("_");
    String[] numbers = splitLine[1].split(" ");
    Integer sum = Stream.of(numbers).mapToInt(Integer::valueOf).sum();
    System.out.println(sum);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above code does the following:

- The first line creates a buffered reader using System.in so we can read the input.
- The second line reads the first line of the input.
- The third line splits up the line into two pieces, before and after the underscore, by using underscore as the delimiter.
- The fourth line takes the second piece of the split up line, which contains the numbers separated by spaces, and splits up the numbers by using space as the delimiter.
- The fifth line, where all the real action happens, creates a stream from the numbers, maps them from strings to integers, then sums them up.
- The sixth line outputs the sum.
- The last few lines catch any exceptions that may occur in the above lines.

For more info, see:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T...-
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--

Comment: I added some line-by-line explanations. Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String s = "Piet van Gogh_5 6 7 4 5 6";
String vals = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
String[] nums = vals.split(" ");
```

`nums` will have the numbers in `String` format, you can iterate over this array converting each value to `int` and summing them.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "Piet van Gogh_5 6 7 4 5 6";
String vals = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf('_') + 1);
String[] nums = vals.split(" ");
Streams.of(nums).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).forEach(System.out::println);
```